# Changing position of Object Explorer window in SSMS 2008

Tags: ssms

The Object Explorer window moves across the screen in SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

How can I have the Object Explorer window on left side in SSMS 2008?

Comment: You mean you want it fixed rather than auto expanding on mouse over?

Answer (score 11):

Please try
Window > Reset Window Layout

Answer (score 5):

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 you can restore the default configuration by clicking on the window menu and then selecting **Reset Window Layout**:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried dragging it near the left edge of the SSMS window to dock it:

[image]

Comment: changing to dockable or floating, tabbed is not effecting.

Comment: Window reset layout is also not effecting the postion of object explorer

Comment: @user993935 `Window` -> `reset window layout` will works fine. And it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a drop-down arrow at the top of the object explorer.  Click that and change it from `Floating` to `Dockable`.

Answer (score 1):

Click the top of the window if it's floating to drag it. When you start to move it you should see a selection of different views in the middle of the screen. Dragging onto one of those views will show a shadow of where the pane will go. Let go to get the one you want.